# How to reinstall ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, reinstall

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 , but when i installed it the laptop was not connected to internet.
But now  the bluetooth is not working and laptop only gets connected to wifi for 20 minutes then it never again connects.
I figured out that if i reinstall ubuntu  while conected to internet it will install proper drivers. 
So how do i completely remove ubuntu from laptop and then reinstal it?
Plz give me acurate procedure.

Comment: How did you originally install it?

Comment: I installed ubuntu using a bootable pendrive.
How can reinstall it properly to make all things work

Comment: I installed Ubuntu from a bootable USB stick as well, and just today I reinstalled it the exact same way I originally installed it. Have you tried that so far?

Comment: Ok it means you overwrited it.
Does overwriting deletes all previous contents?

Comment: Yes; I keep everything important backed up on the cloud, so that's not a problem for me. If you need to keep your existing files, you'll need to either copy them off your drive and then copy then back after reinstalling, or use a different option.

Answer (score 2):

To completely remove and reinstall Ubuntu

1. Boot from Ubuntu **installation media**.
2. Select **Try Ubuntu without installing**.

When the desktop appears - open **GParted**.

3. Format the Ubuntu partition with **ext4**.
4. Close GParted, click on **Install Ubuntu**.
5. When asked - **choose Something else**.
6. Select the partition **formatted before**.
7. Then select **/** (root) as the mount point.
8. Start installing Ubuntu to this partition.

Comment: When i live boot ubuntu 14.04 from installation media, i cannot find gparted.

Comment: @Manishsakpal : Press the Windows key and type GParted. :)

Comment: What about my wifi and bluetooth problem

Comment: @Manishsakpal : The best and recommended way while installing is to have the laptop connected to the internet using an ethernet cable. :)

Comment: What are its advantages?

Comment: @Manishsakpal : The advantage is a stable connection and in case the WiFi adapter needs special drivers, they can be installed properly. :)

Comment: My bluetooth is also not working, how can i make it to work?

Comment: @Manishsakpal : Install the Bluetooth and WiFI drivers after having installed the main operating system. :)

Comment: Could you plz tell me how to install these wifi and bluetooth drivers

Comment: @Manishsakpal : Please write a new question concerning this special topic. :)

Comment: @Manishsakpal: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**
And if you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: @cl-netbox, +1 Very thank you for this I am trying this. I want to know that I `dev/nvme0n1p3   ext4  203.17GiB` is this need to be formatted as per you 3 option. And I need to select _Format to_ ext4. Please help me.

Comment: @L.K. : In case /dev/nvme0n1p3 is the partition you have Ubuntu installed on, yes - select format to ext4 ... although in GParted the partition should  show as /dev/sda1 for example and nvme0n1p3 as label (name).