# How do I install/uninstall software when I am not the administrator?

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, administration

I bought a laptop from a guy who has reprogrammed it and is still the device administrator, which means I can not install or uninstall any software or programs and I have no control over my device.

Comment: You can consider [resetting the administrative password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).

Comment: Or if it would be better, [reinstall Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/703559/301745).

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to reinstall ubuntu. If the person is a friend you could ask for the password. Otherwise there is the possibility that some form of malware was added to the installation. follow one of the many guides online to backing up your files and reinstalling ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Simple insert an live USB/dvd and delete the existing system. If you do want to use Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: Chances are OP has some data worth keeping.

Comment: Delete the system... then what? There would be no OS at that point.

Comment: When you insert a live USB/dvd of Ubuntu, you can choose to erase the existing system and install the new one, so you can have a fresh start